# 10s4p battery layout

Tags: batteries

Here is a 5 column x 8 row, 10s4p (36V) battery, the physical layout is given and I can not change it. Here is the layout:

[image]

Is there any problem with this layout for an ebike with a simple 250W front hub? If am not wrong it takes max around 10-12A at full throttle (which is not continuous).

Here is the finished battery (please don't look at the weldings, it is my first battery build):

[image]

I beefed up the right busbar in pyramid style. Is this design sufficient for my use, or is there a better one?

Comment: Doesn't look too shabby imo. 
Did you use all new cells? Or did you just add cells?

Comment: These were reclaimed MJ1 cells from nkon, the capacity of the finished battery is a little above 13,1Ah (discharged @4A until BMS kicked in). The welding job looks terrible on 1-2 places, where I needed to use an used nickel strip (10cm was missing at the end). I already ordered H strips, so it will look better next time. I replaced all the cells, originally it was 10s2p (20 cell in total) with half of the capacity.

Comment: I think you posted the old layout in another question. 
The welding is fine imo. Doesn't have to win beauty contests. The width of the bridges should also be sufficient.
Make sure you test the heat dissipation in your case still is sufficient after adding more cells. 
The main issue with parallel Lithium cells is even internal resistance and capacity.
That is why I asked about the cells. I assume you measured and balanced them before the welding?

Comment: @S_G thank you for the reply. Yes, I checked every cell before welding. They were 99,9% similar in term of voltage/ internal resistance / capacity.